# Changing Unknown Category

Tags: r

I have downloaded data from web and it has all column name as V1, V2 etc which I am changing using `setnames` from `data.table` package.
One of the renamed variable is married. When I run the table statement

```
table(mydat$Married)
```

The result is

```
?    l      u    y   
6    2     519  163
```

These are # of obs per category. Now I need to change ? and l into y and u. I have tried

```
gsub("?","y",mydat)
```

However, this does not change anything. How should I achieve this.

Comment: CAn you provide a reproducible example ?

Comment: You probably need to do `gsub("?","y",mydat$Married, fixed = TRUE)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, we don't know much about your data, but something like this should work. It uses dplyr's `recode` function to change the values inside `Married`. I've created a new variable `cat`, just to show the difference.

```
tibble::tibble(
  Married = c("u", "l", "u", "?", "y", "y", "l", "?", "u")
) %>% dplyr::mutate(cat = dplyr::recode(Married,
  "l" = "u",
  "?" = "y"
))
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 9 x 2
  Married   cat
    <chr> <chr>
1       u     u
2       l     u
3       u     u
4       ?     y
5       y     y
6       y     y
7       l     u
8       ?     y
9       u     u
```